# Rails - Iterating a Nested Attributes of has_many association before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model and a has_many association.

Say,

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines, class_name: 'InvoiceLine', inverse_of: :invoice, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lines, reject_if: :invalid_line, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Is it possible for me to iterate through the lines before it is saved (especially during an update), either in InvoicesController or in Invoice model?

When I iterate on the existing record during an update, I get old lines, not the updated lines from the view.

Currently I am doing the following in the controller. I am not quite happy with this.

```
total = params["invoice"]["lines_attributes"].
          map{|k,v| [v["amount"], v["_destroy"]]}.
          select{|x| x[1] == "false"}.
          map{|x| x[0].to_f}.
          inject {|total, amount| total + amount}
```

Comment: It's possible but I'd need to see the controller to make specific suggestions

Comment: I have updated the question, with what I am doing currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes) and [marked_for_destruction?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation/marked_for_destruction%3F) as:

> @invoice.assign_attributes(params[:invoice])
>   total = @invoice.lines.select(&:marked_for_destruction?).map(&:amount).sum
>   @invoice.save  #save all on db